# Is it good to start a sentence with 'And'?

Tags: grammar

In my impression, this is very very common in the bible.

But how about scientific writing?

Comment: It would be unusual in formal writing.

Comment: Not "good" -- some style manuals do not allow it.

Comment: And you may inconvenience the reader as well -- it often affects readability.

Comment: Some may say not to start a sentence with a conjunction.  And others may say there is nothing wrong with it.  I'm with the second group.

Comment: It's okay. But it would be slightly better to avoid it in formal papers. And it's debatable.

Comment: (1) Which version/s of the Bible? Modern ones? (2) Many authors use 'And' (judiciously) at the start of a sentence for a staccato effect, adding emphasis and drama to a narrative. Many good authors. (3) This effect is better avoided in formal scientific writing. (4) This has been addressed on ELU before. And more than once.

Answer (score -1):

I was taught that it was incorrect to start a sentence with a conjunction.Although in some cases you can open your sentence with a conjuction /linker.

Comment: {wonders to himself if that was deliberate irony, or...}